# Chrome devtools thinks destructuring assignment creates a block scope

Tags: javascript, scope, google-chrome-devtools

The Chrome devtools has a Scope panel indicating the scope of the variables in the current scope. This can be used when stepping through code. It has subsections for local, global, module and also block scope. So if a variable is locally scoped it will show up under the local scope subsection.

But with the following bit of code the devtools tell me `_c` is **block** scoped and `_d` is locally scoped. The only difference between the two bits of code is that I destructure in the function header.

```js
[[1, 2]].forEach(([_a, _b]) => {
  const _c = 1; // Block scoped
  debugger;
});

[[1, 2]].forEach(_number => {
  const _d = 1; // Local scoped
  debugger;
});
```

[image: The Scope panel in the Source panel]

I can't think of a reason why `_c` would be block scoped. Am I missing something? Could this be a Chrome bug? I'm running version `108.0.5359.124`

To easily reproduce here's a full HTML doc you can copy paste.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script>
    [[1, 2]].forEach(([_a, _b]) => {
      const _c = 1; // Block scoped
      debugger;
    });

    [[1, 2]].forEach(_number => {
      const _d = 1; // Local scoped
      debugger;
    });
  </script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  See the console

</body>

</html>
```

I don't think the fact that `const` and `let` are block-scoped has anything to do with it. If you run this code you'll see that `_e` and `_f` are correctly marked as scoped to the block by the devtools.

```js
(() => { // An IIFE so we get local function scope
  if (true) {
    // In a block
    const _e = 1;
    let _f = 2;
    var _g = 3;
    debugger; // _e and _f are block scoped so available here
    // _g is locally scoped so also available here
  }
  debugger;
  // _e and _f are block scoped so NOT available here
  // _g is locally scoped so also available here
})();
```

Comment: `const` and `let` are block-scoped per JS specification ([here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations) + [step 4 here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-block)) so the devtools bug is in the second case.

Comment: @wOxxOm I understand the block-scoping-ness of `const` and `var` to mean: "if they are defined in a block then they are scoped to that block" in contrast to `var`: if a variable is created with `var` inside a block it's **not** scoped to the block but to the scope surrounding the block. I'll add some code to demonstrate.

Comment: Also @wOxxOm what would be the block in the second example?

Comment: In this case the block is the entire function so block scoped and local scoped are the same in this case. If you instead do `[[1, 2]].forEach(([_a, _b]) => {if(true){ const _d = 1; debugger; }});` (note the `if(true)` which causes there to be a difference between block scoped and local scoped), then `_d` will also be block scoped as expected. I don't know *why* it says `_d` is local scoped in your example, but it's not wrong.

Comment: Looks like a nested environment is created for non-simple params, see [this note in spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation).